# ternary operator in ng-app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, aem

Iam working on a component in AEM. I have components with independent `ng-app` for each component since Iam having multiple websites in each package and using the same components across various websites.

Now when I drag and drop a component multiple times in a same page. Only one component is working. I sense it is coz of having same `ng-app` name. May I know how can I overcome it. Coz., even though the component is same., based on requirement., we had to make differnt API call and get data respect to that section in view.

Iam having an idea of using `ternary operator` inside `ng-app` like this

```
 ng-app="{{ apiType ? type1 : type2 }}"
```

But not sure `ternary operator` fires before `ng-app` declaration.

Any Ideas

Here is the sample plnkr based on inputs I received.

[plnkr code here](https://plnkr.co/edit/iwY0GGhMzlj6VpYWuLOR?p=preview)

Comment: you should inject the other `app` as module something like this `angular.module('type1', ['type2'])` .

Comment: maybe you can initialise app with a manual bootstrap using `angular.bootstrap(element, [modules], [config]);` after a certain condition (element - _document_, or some _id_; modules - _'type1'_ or _'type2'_)

Comment: ng-app is not real directive and it doesn't accept an expression - because there's no app to parse it. Also, where would apiType be defined? There's no scope. *have components with independent ng-app for each component* - AngularJS doesn't support nested apps, that's wrong way.

Comment: I have created a plunker with above suggested approach. But I dont think searach view template would be included since we are manually bootstrapping inside a div and written condition inside it.. hence it seems to be replacing inner condition spcified. Can you help me out on this.... https://plnkr.co/edit/iwY0GGhMzlj6VpYWuLOR?p=preview

Comment: @estus HI, I have already created independent ng-app for each component. But if same component is dragged more than once in a page in AEM., its is only showing up the first dragged component halting the functionality and view of 2nd dragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue resolved by adding loop to calculate the number of componets being dragged and appending unique ID (ng-app value) using for loop.

```
[code here][1]
```

[code here](https://plnkr.co/edit/GBdEr5RR61TPBTdnKFvL?p=preview)